# PHP Mailer is_a(): Deprecated. Please use the instanceof operator

Tags: php

I got the above error when executing my code of PHP Mailer. I cannot not figure out the reason. PHP version is 5.2. in my free web hosting server 000webhost.com.

error screenshot is shown there;

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ik3n.jpg)

```
require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Colombo'); //this function sets the default timezone used by all data/time functions in the script
                                           //Solution for the error - It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.
ini_set ( 'max_execution_time', 1200); //Solution for the error - set_time_limit() has been disabled for security reasons 

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'thisistestemail16@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'testemail123';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('thisistestemail16@gmail.com', 'Raveen Chandra');
$mail->addAddress('raveen749@gmail.com', 'Chairman');     // Add a recipient
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->addAttachment('uploads/3.JPG');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: perhaps you need a new version of that library?

Comment: Try a different host with a more up to date server

Comment: update your php mailer class

Comment: I'm afraid  the php mail class need to be updated and that too in the hosting server. If you don't own your own server, better get ready for some negotiations

Comment: You provide an error message but not the code that causes it.  You're apparently using extremely old code on a very old PHP version.  You should get your host to upgrade to a supported version (PHP >= 5.5) and then get newer libraries (classes) to handle your mailing.

Comment: I think you are getting exactly what you are paying for. _Remember there is not free lunch!_

Comment: The folder doesn't sound as it were an alias provided by you hoster. It looks as you have uploaded your own PHPMailer library to your webspace. (1) Look for an update of your library. (2) If not found, the error message tells you the path and line number of the file. You could manually edit it.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. @Quasimodo'sclone I download the PHP Malier libaray from here https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer and I used the simple example provided by that page. I am doing this for study purpose so using free web hosting.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
public function smtpClose()
    {
        //if (is_a($this->smtp, 'SMTP')) {
        $o = 'SMTP';
        if($this->smtp instanceof $o) {
            if ($this->smtp->connected()) {
                $this->smtp->quit();
                $this->smtp->close();
            }
        }
    }
*/
```

Comment: Please add a description. It'll help understanding the answer and ensure you don't get downvotes.

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? Why is it entirely in `/*` comments `*/`?